# Langchain showing TypeError when chaining Runnables in LangChain: Expected a Runnable, callable or dict

Tags: openai-api, langchain

While calling QA_generation_agent I am getting above error. I have created chunks and need to create questions, answer based on given context.

```
from langchain_community.llms import HuggingFaceHub
from langchain_community.chat_models import ChatHuggingFace
from langchain.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate

repo_id = "mistralai/Mixtral-8x7B-Instruct-v0.1"
llm = HuggingFaceHub(
    repo_id=repo_id,
    task="text-generation",
    model_kwargs={
        "max_new_tokens": 512,
        "top_k": 30,
        "temperature": 0.1,
        "repetition_penalty": 1.03,
    },
)

chat_model = ChatHuggingFace(llm=llm)

QA_generation_prompt = """
Your task is to write a factoid question and an answer given a context.
Your factoid question should be answerable with a specific, concise piece of factual information from the context.
Your factoid question should be formulated in the same style as questions users could ask in a search engine.
This means that your factoid question MUST NOT mention something like "according to the passage" or "context".

Provide your answer as follows:

Output:::
Factoid question: (your factoid question)
Answer: (your answer to the factoid question)

Now here is the context.

Context: {context}\n
Output:::"""


QA_generation_prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_template(QA_generation_prompt)

QA_generation_agent = QA_generation_prompt | chat_model
```